# Issues with adding a random numbers to an array

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to add random numbers to an empty array 20 numbers 0-99. When I run the code below it prints out 51 numbers and they are all 0.

Can someone please help me figure out what I am doing wrong here.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class SortedArray 
{

    int randomValues;
    int[] value;

    public SortedArray()
    {
    }


    public int getRandom()
            {
              Random random = new Random();
              for(int j=0; j<20; j++)
              {
                 randomValues = random.nextInt(100);
              }
              return randomValues;
            }

    public int getArray()
    {
        int result = 0;
        value = new int[randomValues];
        for(int item : value)
        {
            System.out.println("The array contains " + item);
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Here is my main method

```
public class ReturnSortedArray 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SortedArray newArray = new SortedArray();

        int random = newArray.getRandom();
        int array = newArray.getArray();
        System.out.println(array);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your method `getArray`

the code

```
value = new int[randomValues];
```

is simply creating a new empty int array of size `ramdomValues`.

As the default value of an int is `0`, that is what you are getting

Also in your method `getRandom` you are setting the same value time and time again

```
for (...)
    randomValues = random.nextInt(100);
```

try

```
public int[] getRandomArr()
{
  int randomValues [] = new int [20];
  Random random = new Random();
  for(int j=0; j<20; j++)
  {
     randomValues[j] = random.nextInt(100);
  }
  return randomValues;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a few issues, you should probably set the values in your constructor. You could also call it a set method (since it's not actually a get). Also, your `getArray()` doesn't return an array. So, I think you really wanted something like this,

```
public class SortedArray {
  private Random random = new Random();
  private int[] value = new int[20];

  public SortedArray() {
    super();
    setRandomValues();
  }

  public void setRandomValues() {
    for (int j = 0; j < value.length; j++) {
      value[j] = random.nextInt(100);
    }
  }

  public int[] getArray() {
    return value;
  }
}
```

And then your main method, should be updated like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  SortedArray newArray = new SortedArray();

  int[] array = newArray.getArray();
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
}
```